# how to addEventlstner on each element of a list, and ascess it

Tags: javascript, arrays

If you click on the list item, it toggles the .done  class on and off.

```
<ul>
    <li class="bold red" random="23">Notebook <button>Delete</button></li>
    <li>Jello <button>Delete</button></li>
    <li>Spinach <button>Delete</button></li>
    <li>Rice <button>Delete</button></li>
    <li>Birthday Cake <button>Delete</button></li>
    <li>Candles <button>Delete</button></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can add a delegate event on parent `ul` and check if element is aN `LI`, you can toggle the class using `classList.toggleClass`.

Note, based on your behavior, you should also handle double click, as if a user is adding a to-do item, they might need to select and copy it.

```js
const ul = document.querySelector("ul.item-list");
ul.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if (event.target.tagName === 'LI')
    event.target.classList.toggle('done')
})
```

```css
.done {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<ul class='item-list'>
  <li class="bold red" random="23">Notebook <button>Delete</button></li>
  <li>Jello <button>Delete</button></li>
  <li>Spinach <button>Delete</button></li>
  <li>Rice <button>Delete</button></li>
  <li>Birthday Cake <button>Delete</button></li>
  <li>Candles <button>Delete</button></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: If you think this answer is incorrect or is not required, please share your opinion as well along with your vote

Comment: **script.js:54 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
    at script.js:54**

Comment: its not working

Comment: I wonder why I'm getting downvoted, what's wrong with my answer @TaritJaiswal? I even took the time to explain it to you...

Comment: @TaritJaiswal I added a class in your `ul`: `<ul class='item-list'>`

Comment: Also @Rajesh, not cool stealing my snippet.

Comment: I'm  not down voting it,its automatically getting downvoted

Comment: @LuísRamalho My apology if you are offended. I'd delete my answer but its selected as accepted answer. Also, I was a bit lazy, hence didn't copy OP's code. Just used your snippet and updated JS part

Comment: @TaritJaiswal someone believes answers are not required and not that its incorrect. Usually i vote to close as well but on rare occasions, I answer. This is one of such case

Comment: Delegating to the parent `ul` was a good idea. I'll delete my answer as it got downvoted, but I would refrain from copy pasting other people's snippets :) no hard feelings though.